# Beamer, include frame title in sidebar

Tags: beamer

In Beamer, is it possible to include a specific frame title as an entry in the side bar.
I managed to do so by specifying a subsection before it. Is there another way to do so.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title
[]{\Large \bf My Thesis}
\subtitle
{}
\author
[]{{{\textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize H. John}}}}

\date
{{\small 2016}}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section
[Int]{Introduction}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection
[Scope]{Scope}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

% begin frame
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,,shrink=6]%[plain,]
 \frametitle
{overview}
\framesubtitle{{\textcolor{cyan} {{\large{\textbf{{ Main }}}}}}}

\begin {center}
 {
  \color{blue}
Dosing regimens for pain
}
\end {center}


ddd aaa ccc ddd

\end{frame} 
% end frame

\subsection
[overImp]{overview}
%\frame{\subsectionpage}

% begin frame
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,,shrink=6]%[plain,]
 \frametitle
{overview}
\framesubtitle{{\textcolor{cyan} {{\large{\textbf{{ Important }}}}}}}

\begin {center}
 {
  \color{blue}
xxx yyyy
}
\end {center}

ddd aaa ccc ddd

\end{frame} 
% end frame

\subsection
[Lim]{Limits}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to your solution, but in case you just want to add a frame to the sidebar, but not to the toc, you can use `\subsection*{...}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=cyan}

\title[]{My Thesis}
\subtitle{}
\author[]{H. John}
\date{2016}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Int]{Introduction}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection[Scope]{Scope}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t,shrink=6]
    \frametitle{overview}
    \framesubtitle{Main}

    \begin{center}
        \color{blue}
        Dosing regimens for pain
    \end{center}

    ddd aaa ccc ddd
\end{frame} 

\subsection*{overImp}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,shrink=6]
    \frametitle{overview}
    \framesubtitle{Important}

    \begin{center}
         \color{blue}
            xxx yyyy
    \end{center}

    ddd aaa ccc ddd
\end{frame}

\subsection[Lim]{Limits}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Off topic:**

- no need to load `xcolor`, beamer already does this for you
- instead of messing with the arguments of `\title{}`, which can cause problems with the document properties of the pdf, you can control colours and sizes with

  ```
  \setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
  \setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}
  \setbeamerfont{author}{size=\footnotesize}
  \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}
  ```